# RiotJS <yield/> generates empty output

Tags: javascript, riot.js

I develop RiotJS wrapper for Bootstrap 4. You can check a [live example](https://plnkr.co/edit/WzGvRRoU2FR1Tt058jPw) on Plunker. There is a custom tag

```
<item>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
        <yield/>
    </a>
</item>
```

I use it in the following way: `<item>Action</item>`. getting the following output:

```
<item>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> </a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> </a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> Action </a>
</item>
```

Does anyone know why the first 2 empty links are generated and how to avoid them?

Comment: Can you please post a live example? I guess your html template here is not complete and you miss other stuff. You can use our [riot bugs template](http://riotjs.com/examples/plunker/?app=bug-reporter)

Comment: @GianlucaGuarini Hi, thank you for the interest. You can check a plunker on https://plnkr.co/edit/WzGvRRoU2FR1Tt058jPw

Comment: try this https://plnkr.co/edit/2E2oiXFOCrg4n2P2lzKF?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has do to with the mounting of your tags, along with `<yield />`. Not sure of the exact issue here, but a solution to your problem is by mounting your outmost tag *only*, don't mount every single child tag explicitly.

So, in `index.html` in your example code, replace:

`<script>
    riot.mount('caret');
    riot.mount('divider');
    riot.mount('heading');
    riot.mount('item');
    riot.mount('content');
    riot.mount('toggle');
    riot.mount('dropdown');
</script>`

... with:

`<script>
    riot.mount('dropdown');
</script>`